# Getting last activity date on parent account to update child account

Tags: update

I'm trying to find a way to automate the updating of "Last activity date" for all accounts under a parent account when a parent account exists.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of last activity date (it won't fire workflows or, I believe, triggers), I think a batch process [EDIT: that updates a custom field] is most appropriate.  It only stores date (not time), so it should really only need to run once a day.  You can use a formula (hidden or otherwise) that references parent account last activity date to streamline the process.  The advantage of a batch process is that it can incorporated more sophisticated logic than the formula field.

But maybe such a formula field by itself would be enough?  It could compare the child's parent's, and parent's parent's last activity date for the most recent non-null and so handle complex hierarchies.  Or that'd be my guess, but I've never implemented that kind of formula before.

If neither of those work, you'll probably have to write a trigger that fires on anything that can change Last Activity Date, [EDIT: and update a custom field that way.].

Comment: You cannot update last activity date, it is not writeable.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja Indeed.  Edited to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Last Activity Date is not a field that you can update.  Due to that fact, you would only be able to create a custom field and update that based on the date from the parent.

@offboyne is correct though, I don't believe a workflow or trigger will fire based on a change in the last activity date.  Then you would either have to run a scheduled job to accomplish this or set up triggers on the task object, and update this custom field on the children if the task is associated with their parent